# Do spies in Jasmine actually call the function they are spying on?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine2.0

I want to know how the "spyOn" function works internally. I read that the 'spyOn' function internally replaces the implementation of the function being spied on. Does it keep the old functionality?

As an example, suppose I wanted to spy on an object that sends data to a server.

```
describe("A spy", function() {
  var object;
    spyOn(object, 'sendDataToServer');
    object.sendDataToServer('Some Message');
});
```

In this case, does the message still get sent to the server or does the spy mock it?

Comment: could you please explain more

Answer (score 1):

The message does not get sent to the server. The way you defined the spy, it will replace the `sendDataToServer` function whenever it is called in the context of your test case.

You can specify a more elaborate spy, for example when you want to call another function instead:

```
let mySpy = spyOn(object, 'sendDataToServer').and.callFake((message: string) => {
  console.log('I have been called with ' + message);
});
object.sendDataToServer('Some Message'); // -> will call the function defined above and log the message passed
```

Or if you want to call the actual function:

```
let mySpy = spyOn(object, 'sendDataToServer').and.callThrough();
object.sendDataToServer('Some Message'); // -> will call the actual function on object
```